# How do I figure TOTAL DURATION for specific group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, group-by

I have a table with CARD # and REDEEMED DATE. I am trying to figure out the total duration (in minutes) for each CARD #. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

[image: DATA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take the difference, in minutes, between the lowest date and the highest date, per card:

```
SELECT [CARD #], duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
  MIN([REDEEMED DATE]), MAX([REDEEMED DATE]))
FROM dbo.table_name 
GROUP BY [CARD #];
```